Unity iOS build becomes unresponsive after showing Admob rewarded ad
Unity version: 6000.0.31f1
Xcode: Version 16.2 (16C5032a)
Google In App Purchasing: 4.12.2
Google Mobile Ads: GoogleMobileAds-v9.5.0.unitypackage (latest)
Codes snippet:
    if (rewardedAd != null && rewardedAd.CanShowAd())
    {
        rewardedAd.Show((Reward reward) =>
        {
            Debug.Log(String.Format("Rewarded ad granted a reward: {0} {1}", reward.Amount, reward.Type));
            loadRewardedAd();
            StartCoroutine(IHandleUserEarnedReward());
        });
    }


IEnumerator IHandleUserEarnedReward()
{          GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("ChallengeController").GetComponent<ChallengeController>().resumeAdSuccess();
  yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); // tried both before and after calling resumeAdSuccess - same error
}

public void resumeAdSuccess()
{
    pnlRewardedAdConsent.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    pnlLoading.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    computePoints();
}

Triage: Tried both with or without coroutine, but same error
Error: App becomes unresponsive after rewarded ad window is closed
Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "((target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.rendering AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.networking AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.webcontent))" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=((target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.rendering AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.networking AND target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.developer.web-browser-engine.webcontent))}>
0x12e0252c0 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess NearSuspended Assertion' for process with PID=4156, error: (null)
Failed to terminate process: Error Domain=com.apple.extensionKit.errorDomain Code=18 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x301b905a0 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process found" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such process found}}}
